# Let $a, b \in \Bbb Z$ with $a − b \ne 0$ and $n \in \Bbb N$. Prove that $a^b − b^n$ is divisible by $a − b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, divisibility

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this

Comment: Surely you meant $a^n$ rather than $a^b$.

Comment: It's not true as stated.  Counterexamples are easy to find.

Comment: Under the assumption that John Hughes' comment pertains, I recommend induction on $n$.

Comment: I recommend either either synthetic division (what do we have to multiple $a$ by to get the $a^n$ term and then when we subtract what do we do if we carry it out) or multiplying $(a-b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + ..... + ab^{n-2} + b^n)$ and seeing what that equals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant to show that $a-b$ divides $a^n-b^n$ for any $n \in \Bbb N$ a proof by induction is the first thing which comes to mind.

Induction base $n=0$: $a^0-b^0 = 1-1=0$ clearly is divisible by $a-b$. If this feels cheated, use $n=1$ in which case $a^1-b^1 =a-b$ obviously is divisible by $a-b$.

Now the induction claim is that $a-b$ divides $a^n-b^n$ for some fixed $n$.

In the induction step we are supposed to show that the assertion holds for the successor of $n$ ie that $a-b$ divides $a^{n+1} - b^{n+1}$. But how do we do that? We somehow need to reduce the proof to the fact that the assertion holds for $n$. That being said we seek to manipulate the equation in such a way that we have terms of the form $a-b$ or $a^n-b^n$. So we start by writing
$$a^{n+1}-b^{n+1} = a\cdot a^n - b\cdot b^n.$$
This doesn’t look promising, since the different factors $a$ and $b$ get in the way of writing $a^n-b^n$. Let’s use the algebraist‘s favorite trick: If a term doesn’t look as we want to have it, just insert zeroes making it look the way we want! To have a term of the form $a^n-b^n$ we are lacking some $a\cdot b^n$ for example, so let us introduce it by writing
$$...=a\cdot a^n - a \cdot b^n +a\cdot b^n -b\cdot b^n$$
Factoring $a$ out this looks perfect on the left hand side, what about the remaining terms? Well they share a $b^n$, so lets try factoring this out as well. This yields
$$...=a(a^n -b^n) + (a-b)b^n$$
Knowing that $a-b$ divides $a^n-b^n$ we are in fact done.

I hope this helps you to understand how approach such a proof by induction next time...

**Note** There are multiple versions of induction. Sometimes you need for the reduction of $n+1$ that the statement holds true for all $k$ less or equal than $n$. This is not necessary here, I just wanted to mention that this is a possible tool as well...

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_k=(a-b)a^kb^{n-1-k}=a^{k+1}b^{n-1-k}-a^kb^{n-k}$. Note that $S_{k}+S_{k-1}=a^{k+1}b^{n-1-k}-a^{k-1}b^{n-k+1}$. Thus we get the telescoping sum
$$(a-b)\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^kb^{n-1-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}S_k=a^n-b^n$$